# Open 1 file into 5 versions of the same Flex-based App Engine app simultaneously?

Tags: java, apache-flex, google-app-engine

I have an application on Google App Engine that is made of Adobe Flex [and Java] components. The app has buttons to do tasks related to the app, including an "Open" button, which allows the user to open a .XML file, which then gets converted into data/content that's displayed in the app GUI. Then I press the "Run" button and it calculates stuff related to the inputted data/content. Also, my datastore is setup using JDO. I'm using only GAE. I'm NOT using GWT.

Based on the nature of the calculations (algorithms) I'm running, I would benefit from being able to open an XML file and then click the Run button on my app simultaneously on lets say 5 different versions of my app that I have uploaded to app engine. The 5 versions would be identical.

Is there a way to create, say, an HTML page where the user would provide a link to the XML file (or open/load it from their disk) to be processed, then press "Go," where then the XML file is passed to all 5 versions of my app, then "automatically presses the Run button" on each?

I can do this manually at the moment by going to each version-specific URL for my app, but it takes too long. Do you have any suggestions for how I would go about setting up such a script?

*EDIT: Motivation for the problem*:
It's not XML processing time that I'm worried about. I currently have 2 algorithms that compute the number of particular types of "special points" that exist in an inputted XML file which contains large amounts of data. The difference between the two algorithms is that the 1st searches until it finds *every* special point. Then it stops. The 2nd searches and stops when it finds the first special point it comes across. Using multiple instances of this 2nd algorithm, one has the potential of finding all the points faster than the 1st algorithm.

Comment: Sharding your app like this violates the terms of service, and isn't necessary for performance in any case. It sounds like you want to use the Task Queue, for which you should see @Kevin's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am missing something, using different application versions probably isn't the right approach on this.  If you are looking for speedier processing of the XML file, try storing the file in the Blobstore and splitting the work into multiple Task Queue tasks that run somewhat parallel.

Comment: I don't think the Task Queue will solve my problem. It's not the XML processing time that I'm worried about. I currently have 2 mathematical algorithms that compute the number of particular types of  "special points" that exist in an inputted XML file which contains large amounts of data. The difference between the two algorithms is that one searches until it finds _every_ special point, then stops. The 2nd algorithm stops when it finds a single special point. Using multiple instances of the 2nd algorithm, they could in theory find all the points faster than the 1st algorithm.